# git sourcetree credentials not working in terminal

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Can you make me understand somethig .. When i do a Fetch or Push or Pull from Sourcetree GUI it's working ok .. when i open terminal and do a `git fetch` lets say .. it ask for password .
I use windows 7 , and i have all credentials in Credential Manager . 
Why is this happening ?

And i clone the repo using HTTPS and not SSH , but i want to know why is this happening and what to do to not enter the password everytime i use the command line tool rather than GUI tool .

Thanks

Comment: Store the password somewhere where the command line tool searches for it?

Comment: It is stored in Window Credential Manager

Comment: And the command line tool doesn't talk to it. What command line tool do you use?